# JavaScript/jQuery - Script not working - adding & removing classes, merging arrays - test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, merge

I have this script:

**JS**

```
// A & B is needed
var needed = ["#n01", "#n03"];

// always holds what the user has clicked    
var user = [];

// needed + user
var mixed = [];

// takes care of highlighting clicked letters &
// updating the user array

function hilit ( elem, cssClass ) {
    $( elem ).click( function () {
        if( $( this ).hasClass( cssClass )){ 
            //remove from array "highlighted"
           user.splice( $.inArray( "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ), user ), 1 );  
            $( this ).removeClass( cssClass );
        } else {
            // add to array array "highlighted"
            user.push( "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ) );
            $( this ).addClass( cssClass );
        }
    });
}

// is something wrong here? it works locally...

$("#lorem").on("click", function() {
       // merging -> needed + user
    mixed = $.merge(needed, user);

    // removing duplicates
    var map = new Object();
        for ( var i = 0; i < mixed.length; i++ ) {
            if (map[mixed[i]] === undefined ){
                map[mixed[i]] = 1;
            }
            else{
                map[mixed[i]]++;
            }
        }

        // result = letters the user didn't click
        var result = new Array();
        for( var i = 0; i < mixed.length; i++ ){   
            if( map[mixed[i]] > 1 ){
                //do nothing
            }
            else{
                result.push(mixed[i]);
            }
        }
)};

hilit (".letter", "color");
```

Test case is here (thank you, CD..!): http://jsfiddle.net/uDsum/2

**HTML**

```
<p id="lorem">

    <span class="letter" id="n01">A</span>
    <span class="letter" id="n02">B</span>
    <span class="letter" id="n03">C</span>

</p>​
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.letter {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.color {
    background: red;
}
```

​

**Description**

Every letter inside the paragraph `#lorem` is wrapped in a `span` `.letter`. When `.letter` is clicked, it is checked if the class `.color` is present. If so, `.color` is removed and the corresponding ID is removed from the array `user`. Otherwise `color` is added and the the id is pushed into `user`.

There are thee Arrays: `needed`, `user` and `mixed`.
`needed` holds the IDs that the user needs to click. `user` holds the IDs the user has clicked. `mixed` is user and needed merged.

With every click, `needed` and `user` are merged into `mixed`. The result is that `mixed` holds some IDs twice. Then these duplicates are filtered out, leaving the IDs of elements the user should have clicked, but didn't click in the array `result`.

**Problem**

Well, at first: I took the code straight from my editor, but somehow it's not working in the fiddle. I added a comment where the script breaks. Is this a quirk of JSfiddle or did I screw something up?

After clicking on an element with `.color`, the ID should only appear once in `mixed`. Instead is appears three times now. so instead of removing it in `hilit`, it is added again.
Why is it like that & how can I fix that problem? Has this something to do with my use of `on()`?

Any help is *greatly* needed & appreciated!

Comment: Code tip: `{}` and `[]` are better than `new Object()` and `new Array()`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work now: http://jsfiddle.net/uDsum/2/

```
$("#lorem").on("click", function() {
       // merging -> needed + user
    mixed = $.merge(needed, user);

    // removing duplicates
    var map = new Object();
        for ( var i = 0; i < mixed.length; i++ ) {
            if (map[mixed[i]] === undefined ){
                map[mixed[i]] = 1;
            }
            else{
                map[mixed[i]]++;
            }
        }

        // result = letters the user didn't click
        var result = new Array();
        for( var i = 0; i < mixed.length; i++ ){   
            if( map[mixed[i]] > 1 ){
                //do nothing
            }
            else{
                result.push(mixed[i]);
            }
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Have a look at the documentation of [`$.merge()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) function:

> If you need the original first array, make a copy of it before calling
>   $.merge()

http://jsfiddle.net/uDsum/3/

Comment: Thanks, may I asked what was wrong? I see you actually did not change the code. And you just mean the fiddle is working now, right?

Comment: Oh man, that's embarrassing ha ha ;-) Although that does not fix the main problem described above.

Comment: it happens to all of us... :-)